# Server-defined URL and Client-defined URL in Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

This is a statement of Servlet :- POST to a URL creates a child resource at a **server-defined URL** while **PUT** to a URL creates/replaces the resource in its entirety at the **client defined URL**

**Question** :- What is meant by Server Defined URL and Client Defined URL? Brief Description.

Actually, this is not available on Google.

Comment: Where did you read this? Add a link, if you can.

Comment: **General Difference between PUT and POST methods*

POST to a URL creates a child resource at a server-defined URL while PUT to a URL creates/replaces the resource in its entirety at the client defined URL.

POST creates a child resource, so POST to /books will create resources that will live under the /books resource. Eg. /books/1. Sending the same post request twice will create two resources.

PUT is for creating or replacing a resource at a URL known by the client.

Answer (score 0):

POST: the server defines the URL and the client posts name-value pairs to it, and something happens as defined by the server.

PUT: the client defines the URL, at least the end part of it, and sends data to that URL, and the server saves the data at that URL (so that the client can later GET it), creating or replacing as the case may be, all defined by RFC 2616.

Comment: Thank you EJP, but I didn't get the point what actually these term means. Server-defined URL and Client-defined URL.

Comment: Do You have any reference link from where I can read about these things?

Comment: @Dj_learner I don't understand what it is that you don't understand. If the server defines the URL, the client has to use the server-defined URL. If the client defines it, the server has to observe it.